# Angular 2 Async pipe does not render new values with Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, ngrx

I'm using NgRx Store in my app.

**Home.html**

```
<list-objects
      [array]="array| async"
      (Edit)="Edit($event)"
      (Delete)="Delete($event)"
 ></list-objects>
```

**Home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {
     public array: Observable<itm[]>;

     constructor(){
          this.array= this.store.select(state => state.array);

          this.array.subscribe((a) => {
             console.log(a); //VALUES OK
          }
      }

      Edit(event){
          this.store.dispatch(this.actions.updateItem(event.item));
      }
  }
```

When I edit an item of array, async pipe does not update the view but the values in "array" objects are corrects (console.log inside the subscribe shows the updated value). When I click somewhere in the DOM (open modal, click buttons...), view updates with new values.

I log also in the child component "ngOnChanges" and it doesn't fire with new value.

Comment: What is `this.store`? A service?

Comment: It represents the state of my app.
"import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';"

Comment: Can you post your reducer, please?

Comment: The code in the question does not appear to be complete; how can you use `this.store` without its being initialised? Could you post more complete/representative code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

(Note this code isn't tested).

```
<list-objects
      [array]="array"
      (Edit)="Edit($event)"
      (Delete)="Delete($event)"
 ></list-objects>

export class HomePage {
     public array: itm[];

     constructor( private zone:NgZone ){
        this.store.select(state => state.array).subscribe((a) => {
              this.zone.run(() => {
                   this.array = a;
              });
          }
      }

      Edit(event){
          this.store.dispatch(this.actions.updateItem(event.item));
      }
  }
```

I've removed the async pipe from the template, and assigned the array directly.  By doing this inside this.zone.run the digest cycle will trigger and your template will re-render.

The digest cycle normally only triggers under a number of pre-defined circumstances e.g. Http method callback, UI input.  None of which are occurring here, so Angular doesn't know to update.

Comment: Under what circumstances will the async pipe not work and the zone boilerplate be required? This is a little disturbing.

Comment: Under the circumstances where something outside of Angular is pushing stuff in.  Angular doesn't know that something has happened.  Internal angular classes do zone.run under the hood to trigger the digest (like when you use the Http service).  Its frustrating. And I've been through the same battle myself recently with the async pipe.

Comment: Thanks for example about how to workaround, but we should use async pipe - it is best practice. I have very similar problem without using NgRx Store and still do not know where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
              this.array= this.store.select(state => state.array);

              this.array.subscribe((a) => {
                 console.log(a); //VALUES OK
                 this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
              }
          }
```

Comment: why to mark it as down?????? it's the way to mark up your changes and start digest cycle. try it please. do not use zone. you need to put it by change detector cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Change detection isn't triggered by ngrx store automatically (and it shouldn't) so you don't see UI updating. There are only several things which trigger change detection automatically: UI input (click, key presses etc...), HTTP response, timers (setTimeout and setInterval).

You can solve your issue in two ways:

1. Enable `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and then update your array explicitly with subscribe, in that case you will need to call `markForCheck()`:

   ```
   import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';


   @Component({
       ...,
       changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
   })
   export class HomePage {
       public array: itm[];
       constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
           this.store.select(state => state.array).subscribe(a => {
               this.arr = a;
               this.ref.markForCheck();
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. The second way is to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` in subscribe. But don't do so. And don't use `NgZone` for it.

`ngrx + ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is a good way to improve your change detection performance.